# Búsqueda de datos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un cuadro de Búsqueda en PHP que filtra con JavaScript en un GRID y funciona si yo pongo una palabra y le doy ENTER, me filtra los datos de un GRID, pero lo que quiero hacer, es que vaya filtrando mientras yo voy tecleando alguna palabra, que se vaya actualizando el GRID.

Este es el código que tengo al momento de dar ENTER, manda a llamar este método.

```js
function doSearch_Usu(){       
  var data =  document.getElementById("txtfind_usu").value.split(" ");
   var tbl = $("#dg_usuariosadm").find("tr");
    if (data == "") {
        tbl.show();
        return;
    }
    HideRow_usu();
    tbl.filter(function (i, v) {
        var t = $(this);
        var count =0;
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
            if (t.is(":Contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }).show();
    document.getElementById("txtfind_usu").value="";
}


function HideRow_usu(){
  var ind = document.getElementById("dg_usuariosadm").value;
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  var filas = document.getElementById('dg_usuariosadm').rows.length;
  for(i = 0; i < filas; i++){
    if(i != ind && i != 0){
      document.getElementById('dg_usuariosadm').rows[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Deberías darle formato al código ya que así como lo tienes es difícil de leer. Dale en editar y selecciona el código, luego verás unas llaves ( {} ) en el panel para editar, donde colocas letra en negrita y demás formatos.

Comment: ya quedo, una disculpa

Comment: Publicaste 2 funciones, pero no el evento que hace que se llamen. ¿está en el HTML? ¿está en otra parte del JabaScript? ¿podrías publicarlo también?

Comment: <input class ="text_search" type="text" id="txtfind_dmovil"  placeholder="Buscar..." style="width:350px; "
        onkeydown="if (window.event.keyCode == 13){doSearch()}" /> si esta en html, solo es cuando da ENTER manda a llamar la funcion

Comment: la segunda funcion se manda a llamar en la primera, pero en si solo pone los botones con otro nombre, la importante es la primer funcion

Comment: ¿Qué es el elemento con id `dg_usuariosadm`? En algunos sitios intentas leer el valor, por lo que parecería un `input`; en otros lees los `tr` que contiene, por lo que parecería una `table`. Por favor añade un poco de HTML para hacerlo un [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Basándome en este código (según [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36550/b%C3%BAsqueda-de-datos-en-javascript#comment61514_36550)):

```
<input class ="text_search" type="text" id="txtfind_dmovil" placeholder="Buscar..." style="width:350px; " onkeydown="if (window.event.keyCode == 13){doSearch()}" />
```

Si lo que quieres es que `doSearch` se ejecute **siempre** y no solo cuando presionas `Enter`, simplemente deberías quitar `if (window.event.keyCode == 13)`, ya que es esto lo que esta limitando que solo cuando el código de letra `13` (`Enter`) ejecutar `doSearch`.

Debería quedarte así:

```
<input class ="text_search" type="text" id="txtfind_dmovil" placeholder="Buscar..." style="width:350px; " onkeydown="doSearch()" />
```

Comment: Eso si lose, pero el problema es que la funcion se manda a llamar cada vez que presiono una tecla, y lo que hace es que solo fitra una letra y no me deja escribir mas de una, no las que yo le pongo

Comment: @ArurodeGyy, entonces, por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade el detalle del funcionamiento esperado/deseado.